# wijdatasource error

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, wijmo

Is there a way to debug or get an error when wijdatasource complete is request with a wijhttpproxy and have some problems with the data?

```
data: new wijdatasource({
    dynamic: true,
    proxy: new wijhttpproxy({
        url: "@Url.Action("List")",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    }),
    reader: {
        read: function (datasource) {
                    alert(datasource);
            var count = datasource.data.TotalRowCount;
            datasource.data = datasource.data.Items;
            datasource.data.totalRows = count;
            new wijarrayreader([
                    { name: "CdCF", mapping: "CdCF" },
                    { name: "Descrizione", mapping: "Descrizione" }
                ]).read(datasource);
        }
    }
})
```

With the internet explorer debugger I can see the call is made with a 200 HTTP response to the List action but "alert(datasource);" is never executed.
I want to get the error that make the datasource not parse the data (if this is the error).
In a standard ajax call I could have had an "error" callback to try to debug the problem.

```
$.ajax({
    error: function (error) {
            alert("error: " + error);
        },
    url: '@Url.Action("List")',
    success: function (code) {
        var myModel = {
            items: eval(code)
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do a Get instead of a Post.

```
proxy: new wijhttpproxy({
        url: "@Url.Action("List")",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json"
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is that I caught the error in the controller an modified the object I was sending back to have a "success" boolean that I checked on the read function so that if datasource.data.success was true, then I would process the data if not I would spit out a message.  You would have to put everything in your controller action inside a try-catch block.

Comment: what if the server is down?